# Sort by array of strings?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Is it possible to sort documents in a collection by the values they have in an array of one of their fields?

e.g.

```
Collection:
{
  keys: ['a', 'b', 'c']
},
{
  keys: ['d', 'e', 'f']
}
```

With a sort document like this: `{ keys: -1 }` which should return the second document then the first document.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's possible.

This will sort by the *largest* value in the array, e.g.

```
> db.xoo.find().sort({"keys" : -1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc54fd6d6c31bdde3ecd"), "keys" : [  "g",  "a",  "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc1ffd6d6c31bdde3eca"), "keys" : [  "d",  "e",  "f" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc24fd6d6c31bdde3ecb"), "keys" : [  "f",  "a",  "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc19fd6d6c31bdde3ec9"), "keys" : [  "a",  "b",  "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc28fd6d6c31bdde3ecc"), "keys" : [  "0",  "a",  "a" ] }
```

If you sort ascending, it will consider the *smallest* value in the array:

```
> db.xoo.find().sort({"keys" : 1});
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc28fd6d6c31bdde3ecc"), "keys" : [  "0",  "a",  "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc54fd6d6c31bdde3ecd"), "keys" : [  "g",  "a",  "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc24fd6d6c31bdde3ecb"), "keys" : [  "f",  "a",  "a" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc19fd6d6c31bdde3ec9"), "keys" : [  "a",  "b",  "c" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5254fc1ffd6d6c31bdde3eca"), "keys" : [  "d",  "e",  "f" ] }
```

So the ascending sort isn't the same as the descending backwards.